# Start my app when in dock mode

Tags: java, android

I am working on a car launcher app and i'd like it to launch when the phone get's docked 
How can i do it?

Also, since i have a simple car dock, how can forse the car dock state for testing purposes?

Answer (score 1):

This page should help you out: http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/docking-monitoring.html

Comment: Thanks but it didn't help me much, i don't know how to implement it